# MySQL - Distinct count summary over x tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I've got 20 tables Table100 to Table119, all tables have the same structure, Name, StaffID, DeptID, Description

Is it possible via MySQL to count the distinct names, count distinct StaffID, record count per table?  i.e 20 times?

Output similar to

```
Table100, 12, 15, 120
Table101, 10, 10, 130
etc..
```

Additional tables can be added but they will all start with 'Tablexxx'

I can perform this using PHP/Perl but I am looking at running this via native SQL.

Thanks

Comment: SQL does *not* support multiplicity over tables without the use of dynamic queries and/or procedural code. You can use an appropriate JOIN/output-clause-subselect/UNION ALL, but it will require duplicating each table-related query manually.

Answer (score 2):

You need to build a query to do this, something like:

```
select 'Table100' as which, count(distinct name) as NumNames, count(distinct StaffId) as NumStaff, count(*) as NumRecs from Table100 union all
select 'Table101' as which, count(distinct name) as NumNames, count(distinct StaffId) as NumStaff, count(*) as NumRecs from Table101 union all
select 'Table102' as which, count(distinct name) as NumNames, count(distinct StaffId) as NumStaff, count(*) as NumRecs from Table102 union all
. . .
select 'Table120' as which, count(distinct name) as NumNames, count(distinct StaffId) as NumStaff, count(*) as NumRecs from Table120;
```

In SQL, there is no way to "loop" over a group of tables.  You have to mention them explicitly.  You might be able to construct the query in the application.  Or, you can construct the query using a tool like Excel.

Having said all that, many tables with the same format suggest a problem with the data structure.  In general, it is better to store such data in one table rather than split across many tables.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I agree re structure but there are many tables as each one is assigned to a individual client, allows for clients to have complete control over their table etc..  I would like to produce a summary of counts across all similar tables.

Comment: @Olagg . . . That is actually a good reason for having multiple tables.  You could create a view that brings all the data together (MySQL allows `union all` in views even though it does not allow subqueries in the `from` clause).